# Google Cloud Function random delay before "function start" after HTTP trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to call a GCF from front-end JS many times in a loop. But each actual function start (according to logs) is randomly late.

As opposed to X # of GCF instances spinning up simultaneously.

I've tried to simplify my app down to a Hello World test-case, to solve this issue first.

**Front-end execution (100x)**

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    postData("https://us-central1-api-project-879174689499.cloudfunctions.net/delay-test").then(output => {console.log(output);});
}
```

**Google Cloud Function**

```
exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  await sleep(5000);
  res.status(200).send(message);
};


function sleep(ms){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(resolve,ms)
    })
}
```

Here's the console output (pay attention to timestamps):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw0fH.png

Here's the Dev-tools log, to prove requests happen near simultaneously:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZoEg.jpg

Here's the Google Console Logs (random starts after function is called):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/trrGA.jpg

Comment: Sounds like you're describing the "cold start" behavior of serverless backends.

Comment: Hey Doug, that's what I was thinking originally, but then why are the actual function starts not happening around the same time? Because all the instances (or most) should cold-start in parallel. 

They're majorly spaced out from each other, even with the simplest demo.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what "majorly spaced out" means, but it seems like you're presuming some behavior that isn't documented.